# Laravel column name and relationship name same

Tags: laravel, relationship

Can I have column name and relationship name same?

example:

I have a column edited_by in **mack.php** **model** and I want to get full details of user mentioned in edited_by from users table so i have relationship like below

```
public function edited_by(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id','edited_by');
    }
```

now, if i try to access **$model->edited_by->first_name** its throwing error 'trying to get property of non-object'

is there any way to fix it other than having different names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The short answer is no**. You can't have them be the same name because the column will always be returned if found and the relationship will never be returned if a column is found with that name.

Changing the column name to user_id would be more appropriate than edited_by. It's more descriptive, and it's also the default id that Eloquent will look for. Similarly the relationship name makes more sense being named **user()** rather than **edited_by()** because it returns a user Model.

The slightly longer, and totally incorrect answer is that you can access the relationship with **$model->edited_by()->first_name** this will result in extra queries being run unnecessarily though.

Comment: Whats more: PSR-1 standards says that every method should be camelCase and mysql guide says that You should use underscore for several_keywords_columns. So basically You can use `editedBy()` method and `edited_by` sql column together. Sources: http://www.sqlstyle.guide/ , https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md

Comment: You can have the two with the same name, and create a getter that will return "$this->edited_by()->first();" but it's a bit complicated

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by explicitly calling the relationship method using the `getRelation` method on the model. This way, you can make sure you are accessing the relationship and not the column directly. Here's how you can do it:

```php
// Assuming $model is an instance of the Mack model
$editedByRelation = $model->getRelation('edited_by');

// Now you can access the properties of the related User model
if ($editedByRelation) {
    $firstName = $editedByRelation->first_name;
    // Do whatever you need with $firstName
} else {
    // Handle the case where the relationship is not loaded
}
```

Comment: You are champion!